# How can I position my bottom menu so that it stays above the bottom of the page across different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to position my menu so that it always stays in the same position across different dimensions of monitors but is also responsive when the window is decreased and increased in size. I am by all means no expert in CSS and have had no training so I know my code is poor. I am also trying to make the menu ease in gradually but unsure where to enter this code. Any help would very much appreciated.

```
.HomeBottomMenu {

    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3em;
}
.HomeBottomMenu ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li{

    position: relative;
    line-height: 21px;
    min-width: 220px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: #424242;    
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li a{

    display: block;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular',  Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.HomeBottomMenu ul li a:hover{

    color: #fff;
    background: #25a0da;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdown{

    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: -0.01em; 

}
.HomeBottomMenu ul li:hover ul.dropdown{

    display: inline;    
    bottom: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #939393;
    min-height: 50px;
}


.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown {

    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    height:0;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    Opacity:1;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul :hover .dropdowndropdown{

    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    bottom:100%;
    height: 200px;
    Opacity:1;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li{

    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 90, 235, 0.33);
    bottom: 100%;
}
.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li:hover{

    position: relative;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li a{

    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul .dropdowndropdown li a :hover{

    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: did u try position: fixed; for the menu ?

Comment: When I changed it to fixed, the menu moves down and sits on top of the footer as you scroll down the page. If there is a way to make the menu disappear when it reaches the header, this will solve the issue.

Comment: what do you need exactly ? where should the menu be fixed?

Comment: Basically the menu bar needs to stay at the bottom of the page which it does after changing position to fixed and bottom to 4em (thank you). The problem now is that the menu sits on top of the footer but behind the footer text. I would like the menu to change to display:none; when it reaches the footer as you scroll down the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you will have to use javascript..first find the Y-position of footer , then when menu bar has same Y-position you have display: none on the menu-bar..I do not have a code for this right now but try to work this on your own  and if not I will try and provide a code in a few hours

Comment: I believe the Y-position of the footer is 900. I will try work out the code for the menu bar to make it display:none; at this position.

Comment: Got it working with:
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>90)
     {
        $('.HomeBottomMenu').fadeOut(100);
     }
    else
     {
      $('.HomeBottomMenu').fadeIn();
     }
 });</script>`

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Got it working with:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(window).scroll(function() {
>         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90) {
>             $('.HomeBottomMenu').fadeOut(100);
>         } else {
>             $('.HomeBottomMenu').fadeIn();
>         }
>     });
> </script>
> ```
>
> Many thanks for your help.

by [Andy Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380818/andy-thomson)